# Iteratively apply a function on one field of every element in a list of POJO objects in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, guava

I have a list of objects. Let's say the object looks like this

```
Person: 
{
   id
   pwd
}
```

Now, I have a function that modifies the `pwd` and returns the modified string.

```
public String modifyPwd(final String pwd) {
   // Some operation
   return modifiedPwd;
}
```

I want to iteratively apply modifyPwd() on `Person.pwd` on a list of Person objects.

The end result should have a list of Person objects with each containing both unmodified `id` and `modifiedPwd`.

Is there a way to do this using streams without creating a new list and/or a for loop?

Comment: By your definition, a `Person` object only contains `id` and `pwd`.  If you want objects that also contain a `modifiedPwd`, you need a new class, possibly extending `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

*If I understood the question correctly, you are probably looking for something like this*

```
public class App{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      List<Person> persons =
          List.of(new Person("a", "pwd1"), new Person("b", "pwd2"), new Person("c", "pwd3"));

      System.out.println(persons); //PRINTS [App.Person(id=a, pwd=pwd1), Trees.BST.Person(id=b, pwd=pwd2), Trees.BST.Person(id=c, pwd=pwd3)]

      persons.stream().forEach(e -> e.pwd = e.pwd + "_modified");

      System.out.println("Persons with modified passwords" + persons); //PRINTS [App.Person(id=a, pwd=pwd1_modified), App.Person(id=b, pwd=pwd2_modified), App.Person(id=c, pwd=pwd3_modified)]
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public static class Person {
      String id;
      String pwd;
    }

}
```